# Am I using cudaMemcpy wrong?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have implemented this `CuArray` to simplify array usage with implementing the properties `Rows` and `Columns`:

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
template<class TType>
class CuArray
{
public:

    int Rows;
    int Columns;
    int Elements;
    TType *ArrayPointer;

    CuArray<TType>(int rows, int columns = 1)
    {
        this->Rows = rows;
        this->Columns = columns;
        Elements = this->Rows * this->Columns;

        cudaMalloc(&this->ArrayPointer, sizeof(TType)*this->Elements);
    }

    static CuArray<TType>* GpuCreate(int rows, int columns = 1)
    {
        CuArray<TType>* cuArray = new CuArray<TType>(rows, columns);
        CuArray<TType>* gpuCuArray;
        size_t size = sizeof(CuArray<TType>);
        cudaMalloc(&gpuCuArray, size);
        cudaMemcpy(gpuCuArray, cuArray, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        return gpuCuArray;
    }
};
```

However the `cudaMemcpy` seems not to work as expected and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

This are the values (and pointer positions) of the variables for calling e.g. `CuArray<int*>::GpuCreate(11);`:

> Debugged with Nsight Eclipse 7.5, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit 
>   cuArray = { 0xb6e8b0, Rows = 11, Columns = 1, Elements = 11 } 
>   size = 32  
>   gpuCuArray = { 0x7053e3600, Rows = 0, Columns = 0, Elements = 0 }

The pointer values after the `new` and `cudaMalloc` looks fine for me, but the `cudaMemcpy` does not seem to work.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the code as follows should be enough to represent a 2-D array stored in GPU. You don't need to store its `Rows`, `Columns`, etc. in the device memory. These information are usually only needed from the host side. But if it is not your case, you may want to describe more details about your design consideration. A code demonstrates how you will use a `CuArray` object will be even better.

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
template<class TType>
class CuArray
{
public:

    int Rows;
    int Columns;
    int Elements;
    TType *ArrayPointer;

    CuArray<TType>(int rows, int columns = 1)
    {
        this->Rows = rows;
        this->Columns = columns;
        Elements = this->Rows * this->Columns;

        cudaMalloc(&this->ArrayPointer, sizeof(TType)*this->Elements);
    }

    static CuArray<TType>* GpuCreate(int rows, int columns = 1)
    {
        CuArray<TType>* cuArray = new CuArray<TType>(rows, columns);
        return cuArray;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am a beginner in coding in cuda, but your argumentation seems to be good, because if i call the kernel i will call it from the host and then i can pass the Rows and Columns as a parameter in the kernel. But that needs more parameters.

Comment: However your solution does not solve the problem with the cudaMemcpy. It would be great for understanding why it is not working in my code.

Comment: @JensHorstmann so with your original code, what is your expectation? what does not seem to work? You may want to provide more detail about what you are working on.

Comment: @JensHorstmann are you talking about the three 0s ? If you think they are wrong, at least you need provide code about how you print them.

Comment: i am not printing it. i debug the code with the Nsight Eclipse IDE from Nvidia

Comment: @JensHorstmann you did not tell the debugger the pointer `gpuCuArray` is a host pointer or a device pointer. A same address number can be in device mem space or in host mem space. So you can not expect that he tells you the correct content it points to. You can ignore that.